# Error handling for stream with Twitter's API. (Blank lines and receive problems)

Tags: twitter, binary, erlang, byte, blank-line

I'm trying to modify the functionality in my teacher's module for saving tweets from Twitter's Streaming API. The problem is that if I keep the stream open for more than a minute, the API starts sending blank lines to the stream in order to verify its connection.

From what I've understood, the tweets are broken down and then reassembled, but this becomes a problem with the last function in the code below, **pop_size**.

Pop_size expects the argument to start with a text-representation of a number. So when the blank lines are sent, represented by **<<"\r\n">>**, the stream crashes with this message:

```
Error in process <0.118.0> with exit value: {function_clause,
[{twitterminer_source,pop_size,[<<2 bytes>>],[{file,"src/twitterminer_source.erl"}
```

If I add the line below, does anyone have any suggestions what I should try executing in it?

```
pop_size(<<"\r\n">>) ->  %%Code here!
```

To clarify: I want the blank line to be disregarded and the loop to continue checking for the next tweets. I'm quite over my head here, but I'll try to answer any follow-up questions as elaborate as I can.

Code: (Three functions)

```
% Get HTTP chunks and reassemble them into chunks that we get
% as a result of specifying delimited=length.
% https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/processing
split_loop(Sink, Sender, Buffer) -> 
  case pop_size(Buffer) of
    {size, N, Rest} ->
      case buffer_pop_n(Rest, N, Sender) of
        {pop, Chunk, NewBuf}   ->
          Sink ! {message, Chunk},
          receive next -> ok end,
          split_loop(Sink, Sender, NewBuf);
        {incomplete, Chunk}    -> Sink ! {error, {incomplete, Chunk}};
        {terminate, _Chunk}    -> Sink ! terminate;
        {error, Reason, Chunk} -> Sink ! {error, {Reason, Chunk}}
      end;

    {more, L} ->
      case buffer_pop_n(Buffer, L, Sender) of
        {pop, Chunk, NewBuf}   ->
          split_loop(Sink, Sender, <<Chunk/binary, NewBuf/binary>>);
        {incomplete, <<>>}     -> Sink ! finished;
        {incomplete, Chunk}    -> Sink ! {error, {incomplete, Chunk}};
        {terminate, _Chunk}    -> Sink ! terminate;
        {error, Reason, Chunk} -> Sink ! {error, {Reason, Chunk}}
      end
  end.

% Get a chunk of N bytes from the buffer. If there is not enough data
% in the buffer, get more messages from the pipeline.
buffer_pop_n(B, N, Sender) ->
  if
    byte_size(B) < N -> 
      Sender ! next,
      receive
        {message, Part} ->
          Part2 = Part,
          buffer_pop_n(<<B/binary, Part2/binary>>, N, Sender);
        finished -> {incomplete, B};
        terminate -> {terminate, B};
        {error, Reason} -> {error, Reason, B}
      end;
    true -> {pop, binary:part(B, {0, N}), binary:part(B, {N, byte_size(B)-N})}
  end.

% We should also support discarding \r\n here
% (see 'blank lines' in https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/messages-types)
pop_size(<<>>) -> {more, 1};
pop_size(<<A,Rest/binary>>) when A >= $0, A =< $9 ->
  pop_size((A - $0), 1, Rest);
pop_size(_N, L, <<>>) -> {more, L+1};
pop_size(_N, L, <<"\r">>) -> {more, L+2};
pop_size(N, L, <<A,Rest/binary>>) when A >= $0, A =< $9 ->
  pop_size(N * 10 + (A - $0), L+1, Rest);
pop_size(N, _L, <<"\r\n",Rest/binary>>) -> {size, N, Rest}.
```

Comment: The code you posted for `pop_size/[1, 3]` causes a `head mismatch` error, please check that the code is correct.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also include the message splitting and main receive loop as well. (I know you're trying to reduce clutter, which is good, but there is a code smell here that indicates a refactoring a bit further up the execution chain might drastically simplify this module.)